# Multiple file upload adds only one file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to reach multiple file/image upload with php, but what i get is only one file in my upload folder, form is sending by ajax. This is my code:

```
<input type='file' id='_file' multiple="multiple" name="SelectedFile[]"> 
<input type='button' id='_submit' value='Upload!'>
```

and PHP

```
<?php
// Output JSON
function outputJSON($msg, $status = 'error'){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    die(json_encode(array(
        'data' => $msg,
        'status' => $status
    )));
}

$count = 0;

...

// Success!
foreach ($_FILES['SelectedFile']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    outputJSON('File uploaded successfully to "' . 'upload/' . $_FILES['SelectedFile']['name'][0] . '".', 'success');
    $count ++;
}
```

JS

```
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('SelectedFile', _file.files[0]);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (request.readyState == 4){
            try {
                var resp = JSON.parse(request.response);
            } catch (e){
                var resp = {
                    status: 'error',
                    data: 'Unknown error occurred: [' + request.responseText + ']'
                };
            }
            console.log(resp.status + ': ' + resp.data);
        }
    };

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
        _progress.style.width = Math.ceil(e.loaded/e.total) * 100 + '%';
    }, false);

    request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
    request.send(data);
```

i still have `Unknown error occurred: []`

Comment: i have upedated my question

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `die` call from the `outputJSON` function and use `echo` instead, it's terminating the script in the first loop of the `foreach`.

**Update:**

Assuming that the files are correctly uploaded and stored in `$_FILES` array, this code output should be parse-able by js:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$output = array();
foreach ($_FILES['SelectedFile'] as $f => $file) {
    $output []= array(
       'data' => 'File uploaded successfully to "' . 'upload/' . $file['name'],
       'status' => 'success',
    );
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: i have `undefined: undefined` response and still one file upload ;( this is the full php file http://pastebin.com/4mZx98WW

Comment: Dude, your JS code is treating the response as if it has 1 file, the JSON response you're getting has an array of files, so you might wanna do a loop in JS and print all the file names.

Comment: OK, i have ad some loop, but still have an error maybe something is still wrong with php http://jsfiddle.net/uCg3A/ ?

Comment: I meant loop over `resp` to print the received output, check it out, I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uCg3A/1/